# How can I detect whether my page is maximized (uses up the whole page width)?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

So I know I can do something like this:

```
public bool IsSnapped
{
  get
  {
    return (Window.Current.Bounds.Width <= 500) ?
      true : false;
  }
}
```

but how can I implement a function such as

```
public bool IsMaximized
{
  get
  {
    // ?
  }
}
```

Should I retrieve the screen width somewhere or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows 8.1+, you should be able to use the `IsFullScreen` property of the `ApplicationView` class ([reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.isfullscreen.aspx)):

```
if (ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreen) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Actually it is: if(ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().IsFullScreen) {}

Comment: Whoops! I missed the fact that it wasn't static when reading the docs. Fixed.